# Office365 to Azure directory association:

Tags: azure, office365, azure-active-directory

My Office365 subscription expired and I was allocated a new 365subscription which has cause a problem. As I can not disassociate the old office365 subscription from my Azure directory.(I can not delete the Office 365 applications so I can not delete the directory)

Q) how can I associate the new Office365 subscription to my Azure subscription? and gain access to the directory that is associated with that subscription?

??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was pretty tricky one. It is worthed a whole blog post. I will try to briefly describe the process here:

- Login to your existing Azure Subscription in the management portal (https://manage.windowsazure.com/)
- Navigate to the `Active Directory` section
- From the bottom command bar click on the `Add` button
- A new wizard will pop-up with two options: Create New | Use Existing
- Chose the "Use Existing" and carefully read and confirm the instructions
- You will signed out from current session and the Azure AD login page will come - Here you have to enter the `Admin` credentials from the new AD (Office 365)!
- You will be asked "Use XXXX Directory with Windows Azure" - confirm (this will once again sign you out)

If everything ran smoothly now you will have two Azure Active Directories in your Azure Account. Be careful, still your OLD directory is the "Global Admin" and Account Administrator for your Azure Account. In the last stretch you will have to change the default Directory for the Azure subscription. This will be accomplished by:

- Login to the Azure Management portal using the **old** account!
- Navigate to `Settings` -> `Subscriptions` tab
- Click with the mouse on the subscription to select it
- On the bottom command bar click on `Edit Directory`
- A new wizard "Change Associated Directory" will appear with a drop down.
- Drop down will have list of All Azure directories (Office 365 Subscription) which are not currently associated with the Azure Account - i.e. you will only see one choice - your new O365 directory
- Select the new directory
- Confirm your choice
- If not forced to log out by the system, do it - log out

At this point, your Azure Account should be associated with your new O365 directory. If it doesn't work, please provide all relevant information - error messages, screenshots and if you exactly followed the procedure.

Comment: Note: Though being old and referencing the old portal, the answer is still valid as the settings and options are the same. Check out [documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-how-subscriptions-associated-directory)