# How to add an existing directory as a new AD in Azure

Tags: api, azure, office365, office365-apps

I have an office 365 account who's directory I want to attach as a new Tennant (probably wrong terminology there) in my Azure account. I'm trying to use the new Office 365 API preview against my existing Office 365 account.  So I'm trying to link these two accounts via the Active Directory in Azure.

I log in to my Azure account, go to the Active Directory Node, And select custom create. Nowhere is there an option to "Use existing directory" that I can point to my 365 subscription.

I keep reading documentation that says there should be a dropdown to let me choose that. But I'm not seeing it. All I see are text boxes for "Name", "Domain Name" and Country or region.

Below are two links that mention being able to select "existing" but I'm not seeing it.  Has there been a new way to implement this? Or perhaps its some kind of permissions issue. I'm not being given the option to do so because I have insufficient rights.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn605899(v=office.15).aspx

http://www.clemensreijnen.nl/post/2014/07/11/Add-an-existing-Office-365-Azure-Active-Directory-to-your-Azure-Subscription.aspx

[image]

[image]

Comment: does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26051804/office365-to-azure-directory-association/26053798#26053798 up to the point of adding existing O365 to Azure account?

Comment: No. It says the same things I've been reading. It refers to a ""Use Existing"" option. But that no longer seems to be there.

Comment: nice ... it stays there for my accounts (the drop down Use Existing). But there are anyway a lot of issues recently with the portal, so I just assume it is a portal issue. Wait until tomorrow, and try again. I am raising this anyway.

Comment: This is interesting. Now I see that the option for adding existing, only exists when you are logged-in to the portal with Live ID (Microsoft Account), not when you are logged in with Organizational Account - which is your case.

Comment: Ah. I see. Thanks for poking around. Not sure if I have the appropriate accounts for that yet.  Good to know.

Comment: and as of today I no more see the use existing directory, though there is a drop down, but with only one option - create new. Something is happening there and Microsoft is probably already looking into it.

Comment: Now there's a new portal, but even on the old one I don't have a dropdown with "use existing" option.